# Custom route inside Area's controller action is not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, area

I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I'm using custom routes on some of my Actions.

**Example:**

```
/Home/Contact
```

This default route has a custom route defined like this:

```
[Route("~/contact-us")]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    // Some code.. :)    
}
```

And now I can access the Contact Action through the /contact-us route.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when I try to do the same inside an Area. When I add a custom route in an action inside a controller in an Area and I try to access it, the action is not executed and I'm redirected to my global Home Controller's Index action. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should use `RouteArea` attribute to your controller in `Area`. Following code snippet may help you.

```
 [RouteArea("YourArea")]  //use your Area name 
 public class ProfileController : Controller
 {
    [Route("~/contact-us")]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```